# how do i remove the ssl certificate requirement from local axios get request in react

Tags: reactjs, ssl, axios

i have recently started testing a local basic API request.

The postrman request says that it is unable to verify the SSL certificate. But it works when I stop it from trying to verify it.

When I run the request in a useEffect in react:

```
   Axios.get("https://localhost:7075/api/Contacts")
```

then it pops up with 200 ok, but CORS error, and so no information is shown.

What method is there to replicate the postman situation in react? Or is this the wrong direction?

if I try to access :
https://localhost:7075/api/Contacts
it shows the information in JSON as normal.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the problem here is [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) not `ssl`. postman is local app so it does not apply 'same-origin' policies on your requests. But `axios` + `reactjs` is on browser and browser applies `same-origin` policies to javascript code so that is that.

Therefore, try setting cors on your api server to allow your react app access. for example, [setting cors for expressjs server](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

Comment: Also .. not sure about this situation, but technically depending on the server configuration, it might actually also allow non secure connections via HTTP instead of HTTPS calls.    Most of the time its one or the other, but in some cases the settings is "allow" instead of "require" which will support both.